# Prestashop 1.6.1 How to post input data from form in tpl file to mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, prestashop

Greetings from Greece, 
I'm trying to post some input data from a form located in an tpl file, into a table, in my database.

I have tried many ways without any success. (I'm extremely new in the prestashop module development)

Thanks in advance for any help.

The file where i create the form is:
projectmodule.tpl

```
<h4>{l s='Project Module' mod='projectmodule'}</h4>
<div class="separation"></div>
<form name="text_fields" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                <label>{l s='First Field:'}</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {include file="controllers/products/input_text_lang.tpl"
                    languages=$languages
                    input_name='firstfield'
                    input_value=$firstfield}
                <p class="preference_description"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                <label>{l s='Second Field:'}</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {include file="controllers/products/input_text_lang.tpl"
                    languages=$languages
                    input_name='secondfield'
                    input_value=$secondfield}
                <p class="preference_description"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                <label>{l s='Third Field:'}</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                {include file="controllers/products/input_text_lang.tpl"
                    languages=$languages
                    input_name='thirdfield'
                    input_value=$thirdfield}
                <p class="preference_description"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type ="submit" name = "submit_form" value = "Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My main php file is:
projectmodule.php

```
public function install()
    {

        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/install.php');

        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra');

        
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {

        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/uninstall.php');

        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function prepareNewTab()
    {
        
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->_languages,
        ));

    }
    
    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
    {
        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($product = new Product((int)Tools::getValue('id_product'))))
        {
            $this->prepareNewTab();
            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'projectmodule.tpl');
        }
    }
```

And the file where i create the table in my database is: install.php

```
$sql = array();

$sql[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'projectmodule` (
    `id_projectmodule` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id_projectmodule`),
    `firstfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `secondfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `thirdfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL    
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';

foreach ($sql as $query) {
    if (Db::getInstance()->execute($query) == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "without any success" is not very use full. What have you done? Have you checked the browser console for errors? Have you check the web server error log? Have you looked at what the browser is sending the server? Is the server receiving what you expect? Lots more details are needed. You need to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: I have tried inserting the following code in tls file with {php} if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_form')){
Db ::getInstance()->Execute("INSERT INTO ps_projectmodule ('firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield') VALUE (tools::getValue('firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield'))");
} {/php}  and it didn't work, I have also tried with action in my form that pointed in a php file with the same code e.g. <?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config/config.inc.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../init.php';

if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_form')){

Comment: Db ::getInstance()->Execute("INSERT INTO ps_projectmodule ('firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield') VALUE (tools::getValue('firstfield', 'secondfield', 'thirdfield'))");
} and it didn't worked also. 
Of course the browser console has errors at the moment but it didn't worked even when it didn't have any errors.
Even if i see some error logs i'm not in the position to understand what i'm seeing.

Comment: Server creates correctly the table but i don't know how to follow the route of my inputs data

Answer (score 0):

Standard way:

You have to add "actionProductUpdate" hook in to your module.

Also you must have your custom objectModel.

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    require_once (_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name .'/models/ProjectModuleCore.php');
    $id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');
    if($id_product && Tools::getValue('submit_form')) {
        $id = null;
        // Some code to get if exist $id
        $fn = new ProjectModuleCore($id);
        $fn->id_product = $id_product;
        $fn->firstfield = Tools::getValue('firstfield');
        $fn->secondfield = Tools::getValue('secondfield');
        $fn->thirdfield = Tools::getValue('thirdfield');
        $fn->save();
    }
}
```

In file "ProjectModuleCore.php":

```
<?php
class iProductFnbCore extends ObjectModel
{
    public $id_product;
    public $firstfield;
    public $secondfield;
    public $thirdfield;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'projectmodule',
        'primary' => 'id_projectmodule',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_product' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
            'firstfield' =>              array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString'),
            'secondfield' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString'),
            'thirdfield' =>          array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString'),
        )
    );
}
```

note: This is just a sample code without validation and ...

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your time and effort. But still nothing, no results in the database from the form data. I corrected at a point in your code that had the symbol " | " instead of "} " in the hookActionProductUpdate function, but still nothing. Could you give me some other advice what to look out for? Thanks

Comment: I've many modules similar to your module (with nop). Make sure the module is in the  action product update hook.

Comment: Excuse me for the persistence, but you mentioned that i should make sure that the module is in hookActionProductUpdate. What do you mean by that? Thanks!!

Comment: Just add this new hook to your "install" method and reset your module from admin

Comment: I had already declared the hook in the install function, I also tried to uninstall the module, I deleted the table in the database and I re-installed the module to create the module and the table in the database from the beginning. None of this has worked.